# Android Camera PreviewView cropping

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera, google-mlkit

By using an Android MLKit barcode scanner, I wanted a barcode scan to be performed only in a certain rectangle area. Trying below code to crop the bitmap and after that passing to the Barcode Analyser.

But Bitmap cropping is not working as expected. It is giving wrong x and width values with the below code. y and height is working as expected.

Any help on this issue much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
public void analyze(ImageProxy imageProxy) {

Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapUtils.getBitmap(imageProxy);

//camWidth and camHeight are the PreviewView width and height

float wr = bitmapImage.getWidth() / (float) camWidth;
float hr = bitmapImage.getHeight() / (float) camHeight;

// left, top, width, height are the crop rectangle dimensions 

float x1 = this.left * wr;
float w1 = this.width * wr;

float y1 = this.top * hr;
float h1 = this.height * hr;

Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapImage, (int) x1, (int) y1, (int) w1, (int) h1)

InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(croppedBmp, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());

scanner.process(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Barcode>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Barcode> barcodes) {

    }
});


}
```

Comment: `It is giving wrong x and width values with the below code` Please tell which values you expected and which values you got.

Comment: Hi @blackapps, cropped bitmap is leaving some space at left side(x) and right side(width). Top and Height are fine. I am expecting It should crop the image with the exact dimensions given.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue and found that taking rotation into account before calculating scale factor resolved the problem

```
var imageBitmap = ImageUtils.convertYuv420888ImageToBitmap(img)
            
var rotatedBitmap = ImageUtils.rotate(imageBitmap,imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

scaleXNew =  rotatedBitmap.width.toFloat() / previewViewWidth
scaleYNew =  rotatedBitmap.height.toFloat() / previewViewHeight

val boxRect = Rect()
overlay.getHitRect(boxRect)

val cropRect = adjustBoundingRectNew(boxRect).toRect()
var croppedImageBitmap = ImageUtils.rotateAndCrop(rotatedBitmap, 0, cropRect)

val inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(croppedImageBitmap, 0)
```

This calculation is only for portrait mode and need to be changed for landscape (as width and height changes)